# Finding a max value and setting the range equal to the value

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to find the max value in the "R" column of each of my worksheets.  If the MaxValue is greater than 6, I then was to set a range in the "C" column for 0 to MaxValue in increments of 0.1. If the MaxValue is less than 6 I want to set the range in the "C" column to 0 to 6 in 0.1 increments.

```
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ws1.Range("R2-R6000")
    MaxValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng)
    If MaxValue > 6 Then
    Lx = MaxValue
    Else
    Lx = 6
    End If
```

I have attempted to set up the code, but I am very new to VBA so I am unsure of how to go about his task. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please clarify what this means: `set a range in the "C" column for 0 to MaxValue in increments of 0.1`? You want to define a range object in code? Or do you want to fill cells in increments of .1 until the max number? Or what?

Comment: I want to fill the cells in increments of 0.1 to the max number.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to qualify your worksheet explicitly, but this will get a good start. See comments

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ws1.Range("R2:R6000")

Dim MaxValue as Double
MaxValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng,6) 'this will force 6 or >

Dim dCounter as Double

Do 

    dCounter = dCounter + .1

    'adjust this fill range to whatever you need        
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlup).Offset(1).Value = dCounter

Loop Until dCounter = MaxValue
```

Comment: I tried this code, and it only fills the cells to from 0.1 to 6.1, and I would like it to continue past 6.1 if the maximum of the "R" column is more than 6.

Comment: this works for me. Although I did change `Loop Until dCounter = MaxValue` so it *stops* at max value. Ensure value in R is greater than 6 and it will produce max value. Otherwise, will be 6.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim MaxValue As Long
Dim NumberOfCells As Long
Dim i As Double

For Each ws In Worksheets
    ws.Activate
    Set rng = ws.Range("R2:R6000")

    MaxValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng)

    If Not MaxValue > 6 Then
        MaxValue = 6
    End If

    NumberOfCells = MaxValue / 0.1

    Set rng = Nothing

    i = 0
    For Each rng In ws.Range("C1:C" & NumberOfCells + 1)
        rng.Value = i
        i = i + 0.1
    Next rng

Next
```